# With proxy, NSURLConnection leaks for https URLs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Instrument reports leak for this simple use of NSURLConnection:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    NSURLRequest *theRequest = [NSURLRequest
        requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://gmail.com/"]
        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
        timeoutInterval:60.0];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:nil];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]];
    [pool drain];
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:10]; // wait for Instruments to check
}
```

Leak stack trace:

```
   0 CoreFoundation __CFBasicHashRehash
   1 CoreFoundation CFDictionaryCreate
   2 CFNetwork _getConnectionInfoForProxy
   3 CFNetwork HTTPProtocol::createStream()
   4 CFNetwork HTTPProtocol::createAndOpenStream()
   5 CFNetwork executionContextPerform(void*)
   6 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0
   7 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
   8 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
   9 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
  10 Foundation +[NSURLConnection(NSURLConnectionReallyInternal) _resourceLoadLoop:]
  11 Foundation -[NSThread main]
  12 Foundation __NSThread__main__
  13 libSystem.B.dylib _pthread_start
  14 libSystem.B.dylib thread_start
```

It doesn't leak if the URL is just normal http and it doesn't redirect to a https site.

How do I fix the leak?

I'm using Snow Leopard and I have proxies on for both http and https.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're asking the wrong questions.  Here's what you should be asking:

1. Am I following the memory management rules?
2. If I am, do I need to worry about this?

In your case, the answers are (respectively) "Yes" and "No".  It's quite possible that you have found a memory leak in the Cocoa frameworks.  However in this case, I don't think you have.  You see, the `NSRunLoop` for the current thread retains the `NSURLConnection`, so it's possible that you're just not giving the run loop enough time to release the connection or something.

The point is, *you're* not doing anything wrong, so Don't Panic.

Comment: It doesn't matter how much time I give to the run-loop. It still leaks.

Comment: @davidlin so? *you* haven't done anything wrong, so the leak (if it's a real leak) is not your problem and may be fixed in a forthcoming system updated. trying to code around it now would be a headache and may break your code in the future when it may (or may not) get fixed.

Comment: @davidlin also, I ran the code you provided above and Instruments did not report a leak.

Comment: Thanks for trying it out, Dave. I did some more experiments and I updated the question with more information. I think it has something to do with https + proxy. I'm looking for a workaround if it's a bug in Apple's code since my app does a lot of https requests.

Comment: Also, if _getConnectionInfoForProxy is in CFNetwork, shouldn't it be open sourced? I couldn't find this function anywhere.

Comment: Its 2017 and I am still getting leak PAC:findeproxyforURL.. :(